# Is there a difference between these two variable swap methods?

Tags: java, nested-loops, swap, bubble-sort

I am trying to swap variables in a array for a Bubble sorting algorithm.
Basically, moves the number to the right position if the number on its adjacent right is smaller than itself.

```java
int temp = data[j];
data[j] = data[j+1];   //this swap method
data[j+1] = temp;

int temp = data[j+1];
data[j+1] = data[j];    //OR this swap method?
data[j] = temp;
```

Both the codes outputs the same result (sorts the array). But just wondering if there are any differences?

Comment: You *should* be able to work this out on your own.  No there's no difference.  Please give this a go yourself and verify that.

Comment: The difference is like the difference whether you put your left leg in your pants first or your right leg when dressing. The order of operations is different but the end result is ultimately the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, both are the same. You end up with value A instead of value B and B instead of A.